# Php code for more redirects in one request

Tags: php, redirect

I have a search engine, so I use redirect if shows 0 results on server 1, then user is being redirected to server 2, if on server 2 results are 0, then goes to server 3 to 5.

the problem is that I get in browser `"this site has a redirect loop"`.

this is what I use:

```
if ($search_results->cursor->estimatedResultCount == "0" ) {
    header( "Location:/search/2/" . str_replace( " ", "+", $query ) ) ;
    exit();
}
```

Comment: It seems that your condition is always true.

Comment: If you follow the redirects you'll probably find your code isn't doing what you expected - that or you have 20 servers and what you describe is just not viable. Incidentally redirecting like that is going to be a poor user experience - *don't* needlessly redirect users, at "best" that adds a lot of latency.

Comment: Well, if estimatedResultCount is more than 0 does not redirect, but, if first 2 servers has no results then estimatedResultCount is 0 and redirects to server 3, here's the problem, at server 3 says that "this site has a redirect loop"...

Comment: Whats with the `str_replace( " ", "+", $query )`.... [urlencode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) is what you should be using here

Comment: AD7six, i have 5 servers, there's no other metod to redirect user to another url and avoid redirect loop?

Comment: Mark Baker, that str_replace is from url, site.com/search/1/flowers, if can't find flowers on server 1, then is redirected to site.com/search/2/flowers, and at server 3, gives me redirect loop.

Comment: @BadWolf action what i already suggested **[follow the redirects](https://gist.github.com/AD7six/dbac28f14ea93c463394)**. Put that info in the question. And ... please read comments for what they are - don't put meaning to words that isn't there Mark points out that you're ghetto-url-encoding things and that's _another_ thing not to do.